# php - Convert object to an array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array. Here is the `var_dump` of that array.

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[266]
      public 'term_id' => string '4' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'Test' (length=4)
      public 'slug' => string 'test' (length=4)
      public 'term_group' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'term_taxonomy_id' => string '4' (length=1)
      public 'taxonomy' => string 'filter' (length=6)
      public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'parent' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'count' => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[277]
      public 'term_id' => string '5' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'test2' (length=5)
      public 'slug' => string 'test2' (length=5)
      public 'term_group' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'term_taxonomy_id' => string '5' (length=1)
      public 'taxonomy' => string 'filter' (length=6)
      public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'parent' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'count' => string '0' (length=1)
```

Now I would like to convert that array like this.

```
$choices = array(
  array('label' => 'Test','value' => 'test'),
  array('label' => 'test2','value' => 'test2'),
)
```

Please note: I mapped keys like this in the `choices` array

```
  name key as label
  slug key as value
```

Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

### Update:

This is what I tried so far.

```
foreach ( $filters as $filter ) { 
$filterarr[] = "array('label' => '". $filter->name ."' ,'value' => '". $filter->slug ."' )"; 
} 
$choices = array($filterarr);
```

But its not working as expected.

Comment: I didn't get your question. Actually I spent more than 1 hour in this. I couldn't get a proper solution. I tried using foreach loop like this. `foreach ( $filters as $filter ) {
  $filterarr[] = "array('label' => '". $filter->name ."' ,'value' => '". $filter->slug ."' )";
  }
  $filter_array = array($filterarr);`  But its not working properly. Thats why I posted this question. And no i'm not lazy

Comment: @Bigood See my above comment.

Comment: @Giri Add this on your original post! That's why meouw thought you didn't try something before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that

```
$choices = array();    
$tempArray = array();

for($i=0; $i < count(YOUR_ARRAY); $i++)
{
    $tempArray["label"] = array[$i]->name;
    $tempArray["value"] = array[$i]->slug;

    array_push($choices, $tempArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply typecast your object. And perform the operation you wish as below.

```
$posts = (array) $yourObject;
$choices = array();
foreach($posts as $post){
   $choices[]['label'] = $post['name'];
   $choices[]['value'] = $post['slug'];
}
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` :(

Comment: @Giri Try the function mention here to convert your obj to array. http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like that, but try to find it by yourself next time it's quite simple.

```
foreach($your_array as $a)
{
    $choices[] = array('label' => $a['label'],
                       'value' => $a['slug']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
foreach($array as $object){
   $choices[] = array("label" => $object->name, "value" => $object->slug);
}
```